# array_enum implicit conversion of string into integer Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I included `gem 'array_enum'` in Gemfile, and executed `bundle install` in the console, and included `extend ArrayEnum` in respective `ModelName.rb` as instructed in [array_enum](https://github.com/freeletics/array_enum).

**Privilege.rb**

```
class Privilege < ApplicationRecord
  extend ArrayEnum

  array_enum privilege_value: [:read, :write, :edit]
end
```

**x_create_privilege.rb**

```
class CreatePrivileges < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :privileges do |t|
      t.integer :privilege_value, array: true, default: []
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to insert into the table by the following code in rails console:

```
Privilege.create! privilege_value: [1,2]
```

It throws `implicit conversion of String into Integer` exception. Why is this:?

Comment: Did you restart your development server after `bundle install`?

Comment: My bad, I did now. uninitialized constant error is gone but implicit conversion error arises @MarekLipka, can you help me out with it

Comment: You probably need to define previlege_value on the model as a hash, like the example in the README

Comment: Did you try to initialize your `array_enum` attribute just like the Usage section says, i.e. `array_enum privilege_value: { "read" => 1, "write" => 2, "edit" => 3 }`?

Comment: I tried, still it threw me **1 is not a valid value for privilege_value** if I query _Privilege.create! privilege_value: [1,2]_ @AntarrByrd and MarekLipka

Comment: Did you try to create your record just like the Usage section says, i.e. `Privilege.create! privilege_value: %w[read write]`?

Comment: no @MarekLipka, Privilege.create! privilege_value: [1,2] this is what I used

Comment: Well, that's probably why it didn't work. I guess if you do it according to Usage section of README of this gem, it will work.

Comment: I also tried it as Privilege.create! privilege_value: ["write","read"] as in README, yet couldn't create @MarekLipka

Comment: What was the error then? Was it the same?

Comment: ya its the same instead **1 is not a valid value for privilege_value** it thew **write is not a valid value for privilege_value** @MarekLipka